# Hadoop: «ERROR : JAVA_HOME is not set»

Tags: linux, hadoop, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to install Hadoop on Ubuntu 11.10. I set the `JAVA_HOME` variable in the file `conf/hadoop-env.sh` to:

```
# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

and then I execute these commands (Standalone Operation):

```
$ mkdir input 
$ cp conf/*.xml input 
$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+' 
$ cat output/*
```

but I have the following error when executing the third command:

> ERROR : JAVA_HOME is not set

Is the `JAVA_HOME` variable not set correctly?

Comment: Is that `#` really there? If so, that means the line is a comment.

Comment: @DaveNewton post that as an answer so I can up vote it!

Comment: Here is a solution for this problem. The problem deals with the old interactive/non interactive and login/non login shell concepts: http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/06/hadoop-pob-and-error-javahome-is-not.html

Answer (score 64):

Make sure that you have removed the comment tag and changed your `JAVA_HOME` in the `hadoop-env.sh` as well as the appropriate `.bashrc` and/or `.profile`:

```
# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

should be

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

You can set your `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` for all users (make sure you haven't previously set this to the wrong path) in `/etc/profile`.

Also, don't forget to activate the new change by logging-out/in or by executing `source /etc/profile`.

Answer (score 37):

You should set `JAVA_HOME` in the `hadoop-env.sh` file also which is in the Hadoop configuration directory.
By default the `JAVA_HOME` setting line is commented.

Comment: In the current version 2.9.0 it is present but takes the current environment's JAVA_HOME forward.  The doco there suggests that this value should be hardcoded for distributed setups.  I found that in single node pseudodistributed operation it helps to have it set here.  YMMV.

Comment: Yes @russellpierce, hardcoding was actually the only thing working... Whyever, but setting /etc/environemnt, /etc/profile and .bashrc did not help at all

Comment: For those which couldn't find the hadoop-env.sh file, it can be found using find hadoop/ -name hadoop-env.sh command. In my computer the file was at .../hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh.

Answer (score 14):

Type `echo $JAVA_HOME` in your terminal to be sure your `JAVA_HOME` is set.

You can also type `java -version` to know what version of java you are actually using.

By the way, reading your description it seems your actually writing

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

in the file `conf/hadoop-env.sh`, you should write it in your terminal or in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` then type `source < path to modified file >`.

Comment: yes, the  # is by default there so I delete it and I tried these 4 commands again and it works. but when I type "echo $JAVA_HOME" , I don't obtain it value and when I type "java -version" I obtain "java version "1.6.0_23"  . Is it correct?
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)" . Is it correct?

Comment: If nothing appears writting echo $JAVA_HOME", means that the environnement variable is not properly set.
Type sudo vi ~/.bashrc then add in the file : export JAVA_HOME=< java_path >
export PATH=$PATH:< java_path >/bin. Then type sudo source ~/.bashrc

Comment: I'm following this tutorial http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html#Download : the JAVA_HOME is defined only in the conf/hadoop-env.sh .I added export PATH=$PATH:< java_path >/bin in the hadoop-env.sh file,typing "echo $PATH " the path appears but typing "echo $ JAVA_HOME" a space appears!!!

Comment: @alain.janinm   - your link is broken

Comment: @JeremyHajek Thanks for noticing, it often happens after some time... Here is the new link : http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: @alain.janinm. Could u just tell me what is the importance of mentioning Java location in .bashrc and hadoop-env.sh. What would happen in the background ? Will the hadoop framework take all the jar files of java for starting hadoop deamons.?

Comment: @BasilPaul It's not really about hadoop but abut how java is called (there is a command calling java or javac in the process mentionned by the op). So at some point JAVA_HOME is seeked and you have to define that in your environment. If you don't, your os can't know where the java bin are located and can't run the command.

Comment: @alain.janinm  Thank You

Comment: @alain.janinm. What is the real purpose of giving hadoop location in bashrc  to variables HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME, HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,YARN_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,YARN_CONF_DIR

Comment: @BasilPaul I'm not sure to be able to answer this question, sorry. You probably will have better chance to obtain a good answer by asking it in a new thread ;)

Comment: @alain.janinm   Okay

Answer (score 9):

You can add in your `.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

and it will dynamically change when you update your packages.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me was setting my `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment`

Though `JAVA_HOME` can be set inside the /etc/profile files, the preferred location for `JAVA_HOME` or any system variable is `/etc/environment`.

Open /etc/environment in any text editor like nano or vim and add the following line:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/your_java_directory"
```

Load the variables:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Check if the variable loaded correctly:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy this `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk` to `hadoop-env.sh` file.

`JAVA_HOME` is the location where java binaries are present.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above solutions but the following worked on me

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing `/etc/environment`:

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"`

on the slave node, it works.

Answer (score 0):

In some distributives(CentOS/OpenSuSe,...) will work only if you set JAVA_HOME in the /etc/environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here we provide simple steps to setup JAVA_HOME while installing of Hadoop

> Step1: Goto Java library path /lib jvm

Then set the JAVA_HOME & PATH in .bashrc file

Source : http://commandstech.com/hadoop-error-java_home-is-not-set-and-could-not-be-found-in-hadoop-installation/

> Step 2 : Once it is done then go with Hadoop env file then update it.

After once it is done then stop the daemons and start daemons once again.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this in my env, without modify `hadoop-env.sh`

You'd be better using `/bin/bash` as default shell not `/bin/sh`

Check these before:

1. You have already config java and env (success `echo $JAVA_HOME`)
2. right config hadoop

`echo $SHELL` in every node, check if print `/bin/bash`
if not, `vi /etc/passwd`, add `/bin/bash` at tail of your username
ref

> [Changing default shell in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046192/changing-default-shell-in-linux)
>
> https://blog.csdn.net/whitehack/article/details/51705889

Answer (score -9):

- hadoop ERROR : JAVA_HOME is not set

Above error is because of the space in between two words.

Eg: Java located in  **C:\Program Files\Java** -->  Space in between **Program** and **files** would cause the above problem. If you remove the space, it would not show any error.