# Changing default shell in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment, tcsh

How is it possible to change the default shell? The `env` command currently says:

```
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
```

and I want to change that to Bash.

Comment: This is a good question, but it might be more appropriate for the Linux QA site.

Comment: set it in /etc/passwd

Answer (score 526, accepted):

Try linux command `chsh`.

The detailed command is `chsh -s /bin/bash`.
It will prompt you to enter your password.
Your default login shell is `/bin/bash` now. **You must log out and log back in to see this change.**

The following is quoted from man page:

> The chsh command changes the user login shell. This determines the
>   name
>          of the users initial login command. A normal user may only change the
>          login shell for her own account, the superuser may change the login
>          shell for any account

This command will change the default login shell permanently.

Note: If your user account is remote such as on Kerberos authentication (e.g. Enterprise RHEL) then you will not be able to use `chsh`.

Comment: How to make it permanent? I don't have sudo access

Comment: @mahmood It will change the default login shell permanently.

Comment: `chsh: can only change local entries; use ypchsh instead`. Then ypchsh doesn't have any `-s` option

Comment: @mahmood don't know you have a NIS server.:p

Comment: Which setup file does this command changes?  I want to undo change done by this command.

Comment: @ShaktiMalik I believe the configure file is `/etc/passwd`, but I didn't double check it.

Comment: **You must log out and log back in to see this change.**

Comment: In my case, I had root access but didn't want to mess with any configurations on the actual host. I added `exec /bin/bash` to `~/.profile` and this allowed me to login directly to bash without making any changes to the server. (The original default shell was just `/bin/sh`)

Comment: @BCqrstoO Thank you for this. But what if you type `exit` in bash? Will you logout the server directly or just exit the bash and into the sh and another `exit` required to logout the server?

Comment: It logs me out of the server entirely and I don't have to enter exit twice, but your mileage my vary.

Comment: ~/.profile didn't to it for me. My default was tcsh, so I added exec /bin/bash to my ~/.tcshrc which works quite nicely

Comment: This not worked for me. I use ubuntu 3.19.
The command has no effect.
I have changed manually the file /etc/passwd

Comment: Just added a note to this answer about it not working for remote users e.g. Kerberos on RHEL, due to enterprise security policies. I am not sure if it is possible to allow it so if someone could clarify that it would be useful.

Comment: On QNAP QTS running 5.10 kernel , the method of adding "exec /bin/bash" to .profile from Paul Baker works. There is no chsh command on QTS.

Answer (score 180):

You can change the passwd file directly for the particular user or use the below command

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash username
```

**Then log out and log in**

Comment: Probably a good idea to try ```which bash``` before invoking the above command; your mileage may vary about location. In my case, it was found in ```/bin/bash```

Comment: I can also add that, `chsh` command is part of `util-linux` package; and `chsh -s $(which bash) $USER` should result the same as above.

Comment: There is also `-l` option: "print list of shells".

Comment: it was `chsh -s /bin/bash username` for me

Comment: Thank you! This helped me when trying to change it for a different user

Comment: This is the necessary alternative [to the top answer] if the user doesn't have a password. Without a username (so setting on self) it asks for a confirmatory password which will always fail. Getting a root/sudo user to set it for you this way is a workaround.

Answer (score 20):

You should have a 'skeleton' somewhere in `/etc`, probably `/etc/skeleton`, or check the default settings, probably `/etc/default` or something. Those are scripts that define standard environment variables getting set during a login.

If it is just for your own account: check the (hidden) file `~/.profile` and `~/.login`. Or generate them, if they don't exist. These are also evaluated by the login process.

Comment: Plus 1 for specifically answering the question (THE Default Shell). On Red Hat Linux it is specified in `/etc/default/useradd`

Comment: @geedoubleya Can you specify what is a difference in default and login shell?

Comment: Hi @Betlista The default shell is the shell that is used for a new users login shell when they are created unless a specific shell is provided as an argument.