# how to interpreter form bash to sh for FreeBSD

Tags: bash, sh, freebsd

how to interpreter form bash to sh for FreeBSD
this code

```
DBNAME="spcity; home; backup"
read -a databases <<< "${DBNAME}"
```

Comment: The here string is easy to replace with a here document, but `sh` doesn't have arrays. You'll need to provide more context about how `databases` is used to pick a suitable replacement.

Comment: @glennjackman Ignore my comment, (it was incorrect), the correct way to change your shell (which is what I assume, OP is trying to do) is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13046283/1220089

Comment: it is hard because OS is FreeBSD 8.3. and i don't had some packets for install bash shell.

Comment: databases it is array of database for backup each

Comment: easy way it is interpreter this bash script to php script