# connection closed in Linux server ssh

Tags: linux

I am trying to connect to my Linux server.

After entering the password it is showing below output:

```
Last Logan: Mon Jun 24 12:22:48 2013 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Connection to xxx.xxx.x.xx closed.
```

How do I connect to the server?

Comment: Maybe you broke your remote system to the point of needing some reinstallation

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to enter your server as a user privileges and you see `/bin/bash` file. When you `chroot`, you can reach /`bin/bash` directroy. And you can add your user in `sudo`.

Then you should see directory `/home/username/bin/bash/`

**Edit :**

When you **chroot**, the named directory becomes `/`. The correct shell path inside the chroot is then `/bin/bash`, not `/home/username/bin/bash`.

You will also need to make sure there's enough other stuff inside the chroot for the system to work. You can test this with **sudo chroot** `/home/username /bin/bash` and see what works and what doesn't

And also there is good information about [chroot configuration](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2031679)

Comment: how to i reconnect could please explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

Your user is associated with an incorrect shell. The path to the associated shell "/bin/bash" doesn't exist on the system.

Correct your user's shell from the root or ask the administrator to do it.

Similar question: [changing default shell in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046192/changing-default-shell-in-linux)