# How to use chef recipe to change the default environment variable

Tags: chef-infra

I am facing issue while want to change the default environment variables using chef recipe. My requirement is to change the present working shell (from `bash` to `csh`) and change the `TERM` variable from `xterm` to `vt100`. I have tried some combination but its not working.

```rb
execute 'change present working shell' do
  command '/bin/csh'
end

execute 'change term env' do
  command 'setenv TERM vt100'
end
```

Also tried using script to run from chef but its also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running a Linux system, you can define environment variables globally in `/etc/environment`.

The most simple approach to write out that [file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html) would be the following:

```rb
file "/etc/environment" do
  content "TERM=vt100"
  mode "0644"
end
```

The shell of a user is specified in `/etc/passwd` on a per user-level. For a given (*existing*) user `johndoe`, you can use the [user](https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html) resource:

```rb
user "johndoe" do
  shell "/bin/csh"
  action :manage
end
```

In order to change the default shell for users that are created afterwards, IIRC there are distro-specific options (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046192/changing-default-shell-in-linux)).

Comment: While this is correct answer, it is worth noting that `/etc/environment` and its friends are _far_ from global. They generally apply only to login shells, which is fine for `$TERM` but always remember it's not actually global. They don't apply to things like services (usually) or commands run over SSH without using a shell.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Any way to define a really _global_ environment variable? Didn't have the need, yet, and not sure, if things like `/etc/default/<younameit>` aren't a better place.. Just for curiosity.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is one of the few places where Windows did it right and Unix did it wrong. The only ways for env vars to get set is either call `setenv()` (which is what those shell init files do, at a low level) or inherit from a parent process. There just isn't a place to set truly global env vars unless you write your own init I suppose :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks..

its working after logout from current shell and login again .. but I want this be effective on current shell and don't want to logout from current working shell.