# Change bash without making it default shell Mac

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

When running bash scripts inside zsh-Terminal I want it to use the homebrew bash version 4 instead of the default 3 of OS X.

How can I do that?

I installed bash 4 on my MacBook.

```
brew install bash
```

*Instead* of [using it as the default shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046192/changing-default-shell-in-linux) using the following command, I want to keep my zsh.

```
chsh -s $(brew --prefix)/bin/bash # BAD! as I lose zsh
```

Still I want to run:

```
./my-cool-bash.sh
```

Comment: `.sh` should only be used for POSIX-compatible scripts, in which case it shouldn't (technically) matter which (POSIX-compatible) shell you use to run the script; the results should be the same regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following shebang in your scripts:

```
#!/bin/env bash
```

This makes them use the first `bash` in the `PATH`; which is the one you want.

This solution works with *any* Bash on *any* UNIX-like system.

Answer (score 2):

use your new bash path:
ex, if new bash is in /usr/local/bin/

```
/usr/local/bin/bash my-cool-bash.sh
```

or write first line of script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks but I looked for a more permanent solution without altering existing scripts.

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the path in your scripts; see my answer for a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

you could put an alias in your `.zshrc` file, something to the effect of 
`alias mcb='./usr/local/bin/bash/my-cool-bash.sh` so that you can call it from your normal zsh whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are solving this and you cannot change shebangs (because scripts are in shared codebase) or you want permanent solution, you can use following:

- Open your configuration file for preferred shell. In my case .zshrc (in your case could be different)
- And export path to your new bash.

So step by step:

1. `brew install bash` (if you don't have homebrew, firstly install https://brew.sh/)
2. `which -a bash` (outputs location of your bash installations)
3. copy new bash location (in my case `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`)
4. `nano ~/.zshrc` (or open your shell configuration in different editor)
5. add `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` (the specific path differs based on value you got from step 2)
6. <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd> (to save in case of editor nano)
7. Y to confirm (in case of editor nano)
8. Restart your terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc` (to load changes)