# Exit in oh-my-zsh leads to bash instead of closing window

Tags: bash, terminal, ubuntu-16.04, oh-my-zsh

**Exit in oh-my-zsh leads me to bash terminal instead of closing the window** which is the expected behaviour and working on my second machine.

Both machines run on ubuntu 16.04. My home laptop Thinkpad-530 though seems misconfigured.

Installation has been a while. Cant remember a specific difference.

```
➜  ~ exit
myname@ThinkPad-530:~$
```

Comment: Your terminal isn't running `zsh` directly. You are probably running `zsh` from your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, so when `zsh` exits, the terminal's `bash` session is still running. Make `zsh` your login shell, or configure your terminal emulator to run `zsh` in a new window.

Comment: Thanks @chepner @RavinderSingh13 @triplee!

`chsh -s $(which zsh)`

did the trick! See explanation in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046192/changing-default-shell-in-linux