# Unable to find a javac compiler even when JDK present

Tags: java, unix, hadoop, ant

I'm trying to run an `Apache Hive` web interface, so I downloaded the lastest version of ant (`Ant 1.9.4`), and when I execute the command to produce the `hive.war` file

```
 ANT_LIB=/opt/ant/lib bin/hive --service hwi
```

I get the following error:

```
 cp=/tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_9999_hive.hwi.0.10.0.war__hwi__ae9cmk/jsp
    cp=null
    work dir=/tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_9999_hive.hwi.0.10.0.war__hwi__ae9cmk/jsp
    extension dir=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    srcDir=/tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_9999_hive.hwi.0.10.0.war__hwi__ae9cmk/jsp
   compilerTargetVM=1.5
   compilerSourceVM=1.5
    include=org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java

15/02/23 09:56:59 ERROR compiler.Compiler: Error compiling file: /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_9999_hive.hwi.0.10.0.war__hwi__ae9cmk/jsp//org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java     [javac] warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds


15/02/23 09:56:59 ERROR mortbay.log: /hwi/
Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65/jre"
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler(CompilerAdapterFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.findSupportedFileExtensions(Javac.java:984)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.scanDir(Javac.java:961)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:932)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:220)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:298)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
```

I'm executing that code as root. My `JAVA_HOME` is correctly set at the `.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65
export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

and `.bash_profile` files:

## .bash_profile

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export PATH
```

I want to know why is `Ant` referencing the `javac` at `"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65/jre"`. Moreover, here is my `JDK` structure:

```
[root@ip-10-32-205-19 ~]# cd $JAVA_HOME
[root@ip-10-32-205-19 jdk1.7.0_65]# ls -l
total 19760
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     4096 Feb 23 04:09 bin
-r--r--r--. 1 root root     3339 Jun 17  2014 COPYRIGHT
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root     4096 Jun 17  2014 db
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     4096 Jun 17  2014 include
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root     4096 Jun 17  2014 jre
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root     4096 Feb 23 04:09 lib
-r--r--r--. 1 root root       40 Jun 17  2014 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root     4096 Jun 17  2014 man
-r--r--r--. 1 root root      114 Jun 17  2014 README.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      499 Jun 17  2014 release
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 19902785 Jun 17  2014 src.zip
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   110114 Jun 16  2014 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
-r--r--r--. 1 root root   173559 Jun 17  2014 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
```

which shows I have the `JDK`, and not only the `JRE` installed. I also took a look at similar questions, but none could solve my problem. The `Java` is `64bits`, plus I also ran `source` for both `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

> Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is currently set to
>   "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65/jre"

However, your .bashrc has:

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65

You likely need to run `source ~/.bashrc` in your Bash shell to reset JAVA_HOME to the root of your JDK installation. Then run Ant again.

Comment: I see references to Jetty in the error messages. Can you restart the Jetty web server? Does the Jetty server run under the root account as well?

Comment: All I try to do is to execute the following command: `ANT_LIB=/opt/ant/lib bin/hive --service hwi`.  I'm following this tutorial: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveWebInterface . I execute everything as root, and that command will produce a `hive.war` file plus deploy the server using jetty. I'm also not very familiar with `jetty` itself

Comment: Take a look at [hadoop ERROR : JAVA_HOME is not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827102/hadoop-error-java-home-is-not-set). Make sure JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh is *uncommented* and set to: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65

Comment: That's already done: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65`