# Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found after hadoop installation

Tags: java, hadoop, raspberry-pi, raspbian

After installing hadoop 2.7.7 in standalone mode on a Raspberry Pi on a clean Raspbian Stretch Lite (plus java version 1.8.0_65), I get the following error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
```

This is despite me having this line in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

`printenv` outputs the following:

```
...
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/
....
```

I see lots of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827102/hadoop-error-java-home-is-not-set), but the answers seem to be that either the `export` is commented out by mistake, or to put this in `hadoop-env.sh` - however I don't seem to have this file.

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](http://I%20am%20trying%20to%20follow%20the%20instructions%20[here](https://medium.com/@jasonicarter/how-to-hadoop-at-home-with-raspberry-pi-part-2-b8ccfbe6ba9a), and all is well, until:

```
Start, stop and list running services

1. $cd $HADOOP_HOME/sbin

2. $./start-dfs.sh
```

How can I fix this please ?

Comment: Hadoop doesn't run very well on a Pi, by the way, given that the default heap spaces are about 1G each for the datanode, namenode, resourcemanager and nodemanager... If you just want HDFS, there's better options on the Pi for a DFS

Comment: @cricket_007 each Pi has 128GB of flash storage, and I have 5 of them so I thought it would be a nice little test bed to play with :)

Comment: Storage won't help your heap space. That's all in RAM

Comment: @cricket_007 hopefully `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=250`  would help in `hadoop-env.sh` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's edit **/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh** file and set `JAVA_HOME` for Hadoop. It is the path on which you didn't find `hadoop-env.sh`.

Open the file and find the line as bellow

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/
```

If the line exists and is commented out, do uncomment. Otherwise, add the line into the file. **Beware not**

```
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
```

If the file is still not found, maybe path is different. Try to search it using,

```
find / -iname 'hadoop-env.sh'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have `/etc/hadoop`, I have `/opt/hadoop/` and that file is not their either. I tried creating it, but the error persists...

Comment: thanks again, I still don't find the file. I have updated my question with further info

Comment: @JoeKing Not found ?? It's really strange. Have you looked at also **conf/hadoop-env.sh** ??

Comment: Well, I followed the instructions in the link I added to my question above, and there were no errors (AFAIK) until this point. But obviously I am now wondering if something went wrong earlier :(

Comment: @JoeKing can you run the last search edited comment again ? Still not found?? I've removed already the symbol.

Comment: Oh, I found it, in `/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`  and now it works !!  Thank you !